# Checking if List is Null inside LINQ to SQL query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List lstStudents = GetStudents() //this method can return null.
Now I am trying to run this query on my DB table student,

```
var result = (from c in student
             where lstStudents.Contains(c.name)
             select c);
```

How do I check if lstStudents is not null inside the query.

Note: I know I can check it before this query is run but I cannot do that for some other reason. And if I try (lstStudents!=null) inside query it errors out.

> Cannot compare elements of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
>   Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are
>   supported.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `lstStudents` is outside the LINQ query, better you check before the statement. and handle if `lstStudents` is null

Comment: What you want to get when `lstStudents` is null? Please describe it in the question.

Comment: "Note: I know I can check it before this query is run but I cannot do that for some other reason." -- Please elaborate on that other reason, because this is exactly what you should be doing. If there's something preventing this, perhaps that can be worked around.

Comment: @hvd : This query is part of a big query joining multiple tables. And I wanted to avoid duplicating the query just for this check. I will try to workaround that issue if there's no easy way to check null.

Comment: @Kavish It doesn't require duplicating the query. Just put a trivial `if (lstStudents == null) lstStudents = new List<string>();` before the query.

Comment: where (lstStudents ?? new List<string>()).Contains(c.name) should work, however it is not clear why you can not test it before the query.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Putting it in the query itself means the query provider will attempt to translate it to SQL. It simply doesn't support `null` collections, so I strongly suspect your alternative wouldn't work either.

Comment: Use an extension method which checks if the list is null or not, if it fits for you.

Comment: @ibubi Extension methods are useless here, as the query provider will not recognise them and will not be able to translate them to SQL.

Comment: @hvd I was gonna go with this only if                                              (lstStudents == null) lstStudents = new List<string>();                                                  Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: just return an empty list instead of null: https://orcharddojo.net/orchard-resources/Library/DevelopmentGuidelines/BestPractices/CSharp

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> GetStudents()
{
    return null;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var ed = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        List<string> lstStudents = GetStudents();

        var tst = 
            (from c in ed.Baleni
            where (lstStudents ?? new List<string>()).Contains(c.b_poznamka)
            select c)
        .ToList();
    }
}
```

.net 4.0.0.0, works without problem (I only used different table in my database).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I dont think ?? is understood by SQL

Comment: It works for Linq2Sql. But it is true it may not work for all other providers, it would be helpful to specify which one you use.

Comment: I am using mysql devart ef provider.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
var result =  db.users.Where(x=> list != null && list.Any(a=> 
a.Contain(x.Email)));
```

Comment: `?.` is not permitted in expression trees.